# Command required to customize a field in a record using Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

### Sample.txt file

```
2017-01-01 15:35:18 I had heavy snacks
2017-02-01 12:45:19 I am feeling hungry
2017-03-01 10:25:19 I completed my work that is assigned
```

- Requirement: i need the date to be first field, time should be second field and the entire remaining text to be as third field. (Note: This is a space delimited file.) .Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the file into a single field and then use [STRSPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#strsplit).

```
A = LOAD '/path/sample.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE STRSPLIT(line,' ',3); --Note: 3 indicates the field line to be split into 3 parts based on the delimiter space.
DUMP B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
A = load 'data' using PigStorage ();
B = foreach A generate STRSPLIT($0,' ' ,3);
C = foreach B generate flatten($0);
D = foreach C generate $2,$1,$0;
```